# How to grep for arbitrary string containing special characters

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to get the following working:

```
line='"e[?20"'; echo 'foo - "e[?20"' | grep "^.* - $line$"
```

As long as I have no fancy Characters everything is fine:

```
line='"bar"'; echo 'foo - "bar"' | grep  "^.* - $line$"
```

Comment: The `^.*` is doing nothing useful. You'd match the same strings with just `grep " - $line$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PCRE's `\Qliteral blocks\E` :

```
line='"e[?20"'; echo 'foo - "e[?20"' | grep -P "^.* - \Q$line\E$"
```

Every character that appears after `\Q` and before the next `\E` will be understood as the literal character rather than the metacharacter it can represent.

Comment: Brilliant, just nailed it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your `[` character in your line.

```
line='"e\[?20"'; echo 'foo - "e[?20"' | grep "^.* - $line$"
```

Comment: I'm surprised the `?` doesn't need to be escaped too.

Comment: Ah, got it, grep uses `BRE` by default where `\?` is the quantifier and `?` the literal character

Answer (score 0):

If all you have available are standard UNIX tools then you can do a literal string comparison and string location check in awk with this:

```
$ line='"e[?20"'; echo 'foo - "e[?20"' |
    awk 'BEGIN{str=" - "ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; lgth=length(str)}
        (s=index($0,str)) && ((s+lgth-1)==length())' "$line"
foo - "e[?20"
```